# Affix script not working

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

My script is not working, am I missing something? I just want my `navbar` to stay at the top.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar").affix({
        offset: { 
            top: 10 
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
```

```css
.navbar {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: fixed;

}
```

This rule is overriding `.navbar`:

```
#my-navbar {
    background: url(headers/macDark.jpg) no-repeat; 
    height: 800px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: your scripts works perfectly with me.. are you missing `jquery` directive..?

Comment: do a alert statement like this `alert("i just got invoked");` in your script before and after `$(".navbar").affix()` . It will make sure that your code is executing. Then only you have to check `css` and other. Sometimes simple mistake consume our time.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Affix script working in uppercase

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navbar").affix({
    offset: {
      top: 10
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <p>Affix script working</p>
```

Comment: Still not working, I have position-relative overriding navbar in #my-navbar, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: @Pablo No problem with CSS call something else might be sending problem Give a try over here http://jsfiddle.net/kris1rawat/wfyhjrxd/

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> Is in my head and i've linked my js <script type="text/javascript" src="navbar.js"></script>, I've also tried adding a <script> in my head. Other scripts are working well

Comment: @Pablo Did you try with single quotation mark sometime it works  <script type='text/javascript'> or try this directly <script src="navbar.js"></script>

Comment: that breaks my code, as I said my other js is working so thats not the issue

Comment: @Pablo Is it the external javascript have a look over here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: Changed it and still not work. I have another js that is working $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeIn("slow");
})
 but affix isn't. Maybe it has to do with the offset top?

Comment: @Pablo Can you please explain what you trying to achieve in JS offset() or something else ?

Comment: I just got from bootstrap doc (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) the script for geting the navbar stick to the top.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want to use script for `navbar` staying at the top.. i recommend using `css` like this

```css
.navbar {

  background: yellow;

  font-size: 10pt;

  text-transform: uppercase;

  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;

}
.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <ul>
        <li>nav1</li>
        <li>nav2</li>
        <li>nav2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>dsadada
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```